# How do I check for two keyboard keys being pressed at the same time with pygame?

Tags: python, events, pygame, key

I'm trying to put some features into my pygame games that get executed when two keys (e.g. <kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>) get pressed at the same time. I tried using

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
  if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_a and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
    # do something
```

But it doesn't recognize when I hit both keys at the same time

Comment: And I only want to execute # do something once and not several times if the user keeps the keys pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) to get the state of all keyboard buttons.

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_a] and keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
    # [...]
```

Check the state of the keys when the `KEYDOWN` event occurs on one of the keys (<kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd>):

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    # [...]

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: # <--- or 

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_a] and keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
                print("a and ESC")
```

The same combined in a single condition:

```py
event_list = pygame.event.get()
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
for event in event_list:
    # [...]        

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and \
        ((event.key == pygame.K_a and keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]) or \
        (event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE and keys[pygame.K_a])):
        
        print("a and ESC")
```

**Note: `pygame.event.get()` must be called before `pygame.key.get_pressed()`**, since the states of the keys returned by `pygame.event.get()` are set when the events are evaluated.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks! Does it then execute only once when the user holds down the keys or several times?

Comment: @299792458 Do it in the event loop when a key is pressed